Dax Formula Issue: How my Dax Formula should be change to give me the position with the most unhappy employees?
I have the following measure :
TopUnhappyPosition =
CALCULATE (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Dim_Employees[Employee Position] ),
    TOPN ( 1, ALL ( Dim_Employees[Employee Position] ), [% Unhappy], DESC )
)

the output of this measure is blank.
I have one table named Dim-Employees which contains the Employee Position column, and one measure named %Unhappy. I bring these two together in a table below, as you can see.
(The Table contained the percentage of Being Unhappy based on different Employees' Positions). According to this table, the Output that I'm looking for is the Employee Position with the highest Unhappy percentage, as we have a tie here, Customer Ast and Manager both need to be shown in the Dax Output. However, the answer to the above written Dax is Blank.
Employee Position   % Unhappy
Customer Ast.       38.7%
Manager             38.7%
Advisor             37.7%
Supervisor          33.8%
Operator            32.3%
Ast Manager         31.9%
Total               35.5%


could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

It is provided, the data sample for this question is in the picture (Employee Position is the column for a Dim_Employees Table which is not here as it isn't needed), the %Unhappy is a measure which I calculated.
the output needs to be Customer Ast and Manager
